Let $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function such that for every $(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2$, the function $g(t) = f(xt,yt)$ has bounded derivative

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^{2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function and $M \in R$, such that for every $(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^{2}$, the function $g(t):=f(x t, y t)$ is differentiable and $\left|g^{\prime}(t)\right| \leq M$.

Show that $f$ is continuous at $(0,0)$.
Find an example of such an $f$ that is discontinuous at every other point of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$.



I don't really have any ideas of where to start with this problem, other than that it looks like taking the limit $\lim_{t\to0}g(t) = \lim_{t\to0}f(xt,yt)$ looks a lot like taking the limit $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} f(x,y)$ along straight-line paths through the origin. Since $g$ is differentiable, I also know that $g$ is continuous meaning that using the intuition I have so far, I should have $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} f(x,y) = g(0)$ for all straight-line paths through the origin, but I'm not really sure how to formalize this or where to go from here.

The best guess I have is to maybe look at the function $f(x,y) = x \cdot 1_\mathbb{Q}(x)$ where $1_\mathbb{Q}$ is the indicator function for the rational numbers, however I'm not convinced that $g$ would be continuous (let alone differentiable) in this case.


Hints as opposed to full solutions at this point in time would be much preferred.

Are you sure about  the exact wording of the problem? As far as I can see only  a constant function can satisfy this hypothesis.

@geetha290krm yep. This is the exact wording
